# Latin word for "code" or "program" (the verb)

Tags: word-request, contemporary-latin

As part of a(nother) assignment for my Latin class, we have to write a description of how we spend our free time. I'm trying to translate this:

> After my homework is done, I like to program.

So far, I have

> opere facto, fruor [programming]

But I can't find a good Latin substitute for this very, very modern concept. The Vatican doesn't have one, and the only thing I find when I search is synonyms for program in the sense of a list of things that will be happening.

How can I translate "to program" or "to code" into Latin?

Comment: Unum locum bonum ad quærere incipiendum est [Vicipædia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmatura_computatralis).

Comment: You have corrected *opo* to *ope* after recalling that *opus* is 3rd declension. But is that really how do you decline *opus*?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta By typo. Oops. (I've been using a new phone keyboard and the "e" is right next to the backspace, for some reason)

Comment: @BenKovitz It took me too long to realize that's just "Wikipedia" but spelling like it's Latin. Thanks for the new resource!

Comment: You really ought to hold off before accepting an answer. A one point answer doesn't have the stamp of approval from the community yet, which is mostly needed to accept. What if, for example, they're wrong? Or incomplete? Check out the [meta](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/questions/19/wait-few-days-before-accepting-answers) thread on why.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer It answers my question, so I accepted it. If someone proves it wrong, I can always unaccept -- unlike votes, it's not locked in after a certain amount of time -- and considering how specific this question is, I doubt it'll ever get very many votes.

Comment: Please read the linked thread. It goes without saying that you can do what you want, but there are good reasons not to accept straightaway the first answer that you think answers your question. (Note, this isn't just about this thread, it's just good practice across stacks.)

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I did. In fact, I read it before you linked it. I read it when the answer was posted, give or take, because I keep up with meta. I don't see how leaving a question marked as unanswered when it is answered is a good thing. Could we discuss it in chat? (I'm not in there ATM but I will be shortly)

Comment: For what it's worth, "homework" is probably more appropriately rendered *pēnsum* than *opus*. It's what a lot of Latin textbooks seem to use, and it comes from the past participle of *pendere*, to weigh. http://www.locutio.net/modules.php?name=Encyclopedia&op=content&tid=6507 is in French but begins: "A Latin word that described the weight of wool that a slave had to spin in a day." (The word "pensum" is also used in English—and I believe in French—to describe homework as punishment, but that sense was absent from the Latin.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For almost twenty years, the de facto standard for Latin technology vocabulary has been the [Vocabula computatralia](http://www.obta.uw.edu.pl/~draco/docs/voccomp.html). You can and should use and peruse it for all types of programming-related vocabulary, but I'll reproduce the definitions you are looking for below.

For program, we can just take the word from which the English is derived:

> **program** **1.** subst. programma,atis n.; ~ **listing** textus programmatis **2.** vt. programmare

Unfortunately, there's no definition for "code", but considering the word comes from *codex* and Vicipaedia uses *codex* for Semiotic [code](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex_(semiotica)), I think it's as good as we'd get. It also has a nice, metaphorical ring to it, too.

Comment: +1 for providing a source as well as the definition, and proving my point that if a better answer comes along I can move the accept.

Comment: It seems the *Vocabula Computatralia* link is no longer active.  I was able to locate a PDF at http://www.culturaclasica.com/lingualatina/vocabula_computatralia.pdf.

Comment: @pglezen The link still works for me.

Comment: Indeed, @C.M.Weimer, it's working for me, now, also.  I'm not sure what the problem was back in 2018.  But I'm glad it's back.

Answer (score 10):

My dictionary translates 'to program' as *programmare* or *programma conficere*.
If you find a good noun for 'code', you can also combine it with *conficere*.
One possibility is *nota*, but I'm not entirely happy with it.

Regarding your sentence:
If you want to use *opus* for homework, remember that it third declension, not second.
To express enjoyment, remember that *frui* requires ablative, so 'I enjoy doing a thing' would be *re facienda fruor*.
Other verbs can be used in other ways, like *res facienda mihi delectat* or *rem facere mihi delectat*.
Since it is a homework assignment, I will not propose any full translation, but leave the work to you.

Comment: What dictionary are you using?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, it is a Finnish-Latin-Finnish dictionary by Reijo Pitkäranta. I typically use that or a Latin-Finnish dictionary by Adolf Streng. I don't have any dictionaries between Latin and English. If you study Latin in Finnish, you already know these books, and if not, you have probably no use for them...

Comment: Apologies, but I'm unaccepting this answer, because the other one provides a reference [that I can read]

Answer (score 1):

How about encifrāre, a neologism from cifra ou cifera, Medieval Latin for Arabic sifr, "zero"? Programmers ultimately reduce things to zeros and ones and owe a debt of thanks to the Arab mathematicians for inventing nothingness!

Comment: I... Don't see how this answers my question. If you want to leave a comment on another post, you'll be able to do that once you have 50 reputation.

Comment: I agree with @QPaysTaxes that this does not exactly answer the question. Perhaps you could edit your answer to include only the answer to the question presented at the top of this page? Asking about "open source" is a good idea, but that should be done by asking a separate question. Yes, programma is of Greek origin. (Perhaps that leads to a Greek verb for programming, like *programmatizein*, which could then be Latinized?) And welcome to the site! May I suggest that you take a look at our [tour](http://latin.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Umm. Zero came to Western Europe *through* the Arabs, but they got it from trade with India. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=who+invented+zero *In fine*, it appears to have been invented independently several times.