# How does a computer crash in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, verbs, contemporary-latin, technology, modern-life

I wrote up a lengthy question to ask here, but my computer crashed and I lost it.
Instead of reproducing the question just now, I would like to know how to describe the situation in Latin.
The only thing I am missing is a good verb for crashing.
Which word should I use and why?

My best guess now is *mugire*, so I might write something like this:

> *Computatrum meum mugivit, et ita rogatum meum amisi.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://www.obta.uw.edu.pl/~draco/docs/voccomp.html) was cited in [the answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/196/latin-word-for-code-or-program-the-verb) to a recent question as the *de facto standard for Latin technology vocabulary* by C. M. Weimer.

Acording to it, the verbs *corruo* and *collabor* are enough for a *soft* crash. L&S cites [corruo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcorruo) as *to fall, sink to the ground* and with an active meaning of someone *to ruin* sth. Meanwhile, [collabor](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcollabor) is more explicit in meaning *to fall in ruins* (for buildings, though).

My guess as a choice to more properly mean that it was not just a matter of restarting your computer is:

> *Computatrum meum collapsit*

Comment: Tibi gratulor, quod iam mille puncta tulisti!

Comment: Gratias tibi do, care conlocutor! Dolet mihi frequentius hic scribere non posse