# Quo modo dicitur "application"?

Tags: contemporary-latin, word-request, technology

Qua voce Latina tradidi potest vox Anglica "application"?
Non de theoria adhibenda ago, sed de programmatis telephonulorum (sive telephonorum mobilium) vel computatrorum hac voce Anglica appellatis.
Nescio an "applicatio", e quo vox illa Anglica orta est, aptum sit.
Quibus vocibus uteris si hanc rem Latine describere debes, et quare?

[Hoc rogatum](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/196/79) verbum "to program" sive "to code" petit.
Dissimile mihi videtur vocem "application" Latine reddere, quamvis hae res forsitan connexus inter se habent.
Fieri potest, ut neologismo utendum sit — Romani antiqui talis technologiae egebant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latin word for "code" or "program" (the verb)](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/196/latin-word-for-code-or-program-the-verb)

Comment: To further clarify, in the answer is also the noun "program," which is synonymous with application, i.e. a compiled executable. I know that on other stacks even if the question is different, if the answer is the same, they're usually redirected. In any case, you can find your answer in the link provided there, too.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer There is a difference between a program and an application. A slight one, perhaps, but the two English words are not exactly synonymous to many people. If this is not the case in Latin and the best word is indeed *programma (telephonulare?)*, then explaining that would make a good answer. I read through the other question, but I did not find an answer to my question.

Comment: Are you going along this route? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4433145/4117603

Comment: @C.M.Weimer That looks like an excellent definition to me. A word for an application in that sense would be perfect.

Comment: Timeo ne hoc rogatum aptum accipere responsum nequeat, cum sensus verborum latinorum circa res informaticas nec antiqua auctoritate nec usu moderno confirmetur, ita ut voces inter se tam paulum differentes capere non possit. Si "programma" respuimus, opportebit, ut mihi videtur, optimum responsum quemdam neologismum esse, fortasse quo intellegi possit sensus vocis anglicae "interface."

Answer (score 1):

*Applicatio,* id est *programma informaticum cum interfacie ad utentes,* ab omnibus facile intellegitur, mihique tantum sufficit.