# Composing a question with hortari and an ut-clause

Tags: classical-latin, syntax, interrogative

When I was composing [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2453/79) yesterday, I wanted to ask this:

> Which words would you suggest me to use?

I wanted to do it using *hortari* and an *ut*-clause.
I was looking for a question form of this statement:

> You suggest that I use these words.
>   *Me hortaris, ut his vocibus utar.*

How to convert this into a question?
I was unable to do so, so I worked around it, but I would still like to know.

Without the suggestion the conversion would be easy: *his vobibus utor* becomes *quibus vocibus utor?* ("which words do I use?").
But replacing the pronoun *his* with an interrogative sounds awfully fishy if it happens in a subordinate clause:

> *Me hortaris, ut quibus vocibus utar?*

I could break the subordinate clause and bring *quibus* to a position where it sounds like an interrogative pronoun:

> *Quibus vocibus me hortaris, ut utar?*

This does not sound perfect either, and it is prone to misinterpretation.
The instrumental ablative *quibus vocibus* is supposed to modify *utar*, not *hortaris*.

Are there examples of questions like this in classical Latin?
Perhaps an example of this exact structure does not exist, but hopefully something that would help composing this question by analogy.
If such questions are nowhere to be found, I am prepared to conclude that there is no grammatical way to structure a question from my starting point.
In that case I would like suggestions for asking my question in good classical Latin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your last sentence is grammatically correct. The general question is whether it's possible to raise an interrogative out of an *ut* clause, and there are examples of this:

> Quid vis ut curem? ([Plautus](https://books.google.com/books?id=4-UNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA741&lpg=PA741&dq=%22quid+vis+ut%22&source=bl&ots=U9iKaaOUca&sig=-jcwtCfuxSfqp2nUIL5gxDcnt6M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF5PyWmdLRAhXnsVQKHXt7B3o4FBDoAQgeMAE#v=onepage&q=%22quid%20vis%20ut%22&f=false))
>   Quid vis ut faciam? ([Vulgate](http://www.biblestudytools.com/vul/2-kings/4-2.html))
>   Quid iubes ut faciam, domina? ([Patrologia Latina](http://www.mlat.uzh.ch/MLS/xfromcc.php?tabelle=Ioannes_Italus_cps2&rumpfid=Ioannes_Italus_cps2,%20Vita%20S.%20Odonis,%20%20%20%20p42&id=Ioannes_Italus_cps2,%20Vita%20S.%20Odonis,%20%20%20%20p42,%20%20%20%20%2025&level=99&level9798=&satz=25&hilite_id=Ioannes_Italus_cps2,%20Vita%20S.%20Odonis,%20%20%20%20p42,%20%20%20%20%2025&string=DOMINA&binary=&corpus=2&target=&lang=0&home=&von=suchergebnis&hide_apparatus=1&inframe=1&jumpto=25#25))

Probably more classical examples could be found, but this is a hard thing to search for. But these examples have the same structure as yours; the difference of case (*quid* vs. *quibus vocibus*) or verb (*hortor* vs. the verbs above) is not likely to be important, I think.

This of course doesn't necessarily mean that your sentence is the idiomatic way a Latin speaker would have expressed this -- my sense is that some simpler structure would have been preferred, like something along the lines of *Quibus verbis mihi utendum est tua sententia?* -- but it seems to be correct. (The possible ambiguity doesn't seem to me to be a serious issue because taking the ablative with *hortaris* would leave *utar* without an object.)

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty convincing. I hadn't seen an interrogative pulled out of a subordinate clause before. (The ambiguity can be strengthened by context. For example: *"Telephonulo uti nolo. Quo modo me hortaris, ut utar?"* Now *utar* can refer to either *telephonulo* or *modo*.)

Answer (score 6):

I would try to find something that a Roman might have used, and think you would get a more satisfying translation by re-phrasing the English to *suggest what words I should use*.

*Vox* for 'word' is legitimate, but a little too fancy for my taste in this situation; and isn't *hortor*, meaning 'urge strongly', a pretty strong word for 'suggest'? There are examples which suggest that *subiicio* is a more appropriate verb:

*id quod olim dictum est subiice*    Ter. Phaed. 2, 3, 30

. . . *Maeandrius quasi ministrator aderat subiciens quid in suos civis civitatemque, si vellem, dicerem.*    Cic.  pro Flacc. 22,53

I suggest something like *verba subiice quibus utar*, or (more politely/pompously, but something to roll nicely off the tongue!) *subiice quae verba sint mihi utenda*.

**In response to objections in comments** on the second of these suggestions : it is true that the verb *utor* is intransitive and cannot be passivized, but it is also a fact that the gerundive is already passive. In the second suggestion, *utendam* is a gerundive, purely adjectival, passive in meaning, 'fit to be used'. Here it is predicatively used as a a verbal adjective, formed from the verb *utor*, certainly, but having no verbal function it can be used without the ablative case. In fact all intransitive verbs that take an ablative are deponent, but their gerundives are used as if the verb were transitive.

Two examples from Plautus:

*filiam utendam mihi da. /Numquam edepol cuiquam utendam dedi.* Persa 1, 3  ( l.127)

*nam ego quidem meos oculos habeo nec rogo utendos foris*  Mil. 2, 3    (l.347)

and one (using *fruor*) from Cicero:

*etiam apud maiores nostros iustitiae fruendae causa videntur* . . .    Off. 2, 41

[Later] Nevertheless, it has been pointed out in further comment (*q.v.*) that the use of *esse* in the construction I proposed is not known. It would be better, therefore, to avoid the relative  and simply write *subiice verba mihi utenda*.

Comment: I like these suggestions: you have one typo at the end though (*utendae* -> *utenda*)

Comment: Thanks. You are right, and I've removed the surplus 'e'.

Comment: *Utor* doesn't take accusative, so *quae verba sint utenda* isn't a possible construction, I believe -- it needs to be impersonal, *quibus verbis sit utendum* (as with other pseudo-transitive verbs like *credo*).

Comment: Quite :, it doesn't — but _quae verba_ is here the object of _subiice_, not of _utar_. 'Suggest what words might be useful to me.'

Comment: I like these suggestions, too. Thanks! Suggestions like this help me make my Latin more idiomatic bit by bit.

Comment: The point is that a verb that isn't transitive can't be passivized -- since you can't say *utor haec verba*, you can't make that into *haec verba utenda sunt*. Just like you can say *Credit mihi* "He believes me", but not *Credor ab eo "I am believed by him".

Comment: See Woodcock p. 164: https://books.google.com/books?id=WmT6mS5v4dAC&lpg=PA164&vq=utendam&pg=PA164#v=snippet&q=utendam&f=false

Comment: I think you overlook the point that _utenda_ is adjectival (a gerundive) and therefore has to agree with _verba_. The question of an ablative to follow some part of _utor_ does not arise — which does actually happen. in my first example.

Comment: My point is that *utenda* is impossible in the first place because an intransitive verb can't be passivized (except impersonally). Woodcock addresses this exact issue, see the Note in the middle of the linked page: "one can say *ad hanc rem utendam* ... but not *haec res utenda est*. For the latter one must say *hac re utendum est*."

Comment: @TKR I'm sorry to say that the link to Woodcock shows only a blank page. I have addressed your objection by editing the answer.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting a blank page too but if I click the X next to "Clear search", the page shows up. Another quote relevant to the examples you cite is "These [gerundives of *utor* etc.] can be used predicatively ... but they are never predicated with *esse* to form the periphrastic construction". That is, things like *filiam utendam* are an exception to the  usual rule that intransitives can't passivize, but the exception does not extent to the construction with *sum*, as in *verba utenda sint*.

Comment: Finally got there by a new search. I've not come across this restriction before and wonder why it should exist? My guess is that a preference for direct expression to subordinate clauses may have made it (if _esse_ was ever actually allowed in such cases) too rare for examples to have survived. Instead of giving a 'more polite'  suggestion I would better have left it as_subiice verba mihi utenda_. Thank you!

Comment: To me it's the *filiam utendam do* type that needs explanation, as the *res utenda est* type seems to be ruled out by normal grammatical logic. Anyway, it's an odd little corner of Latin grammar. Not sure why the link didn't work correctly -- sorry about that!