# What is the Latin word for “software”?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

What is the Latin word for “software”?

“Programmatura”, “corpus programmatum” and “mollopus” were suggested on [Vicipaedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disputatio:Corpus_programmatum).

Comment: Using the interwiki links on wikipedia you arrive at https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_programmatum

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question lacks basic research.

Comment: @jknappen It's not clear that the translation in Vicipaedia is the optimal one, so it makes sense to ask for a good translation here. But I agree that it would be good to acknowledge it and formulate the question accordingly.

Comment: As in french *logiciel*, and spanish *logicial*, I would propose a latin *logicialis*

Comment: I thought it was COBOL. Unless there's another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/196/latin-word-for-code-or-program-the-verb

Answer (score 2):

[This document](http://www.obta.uw.edu.pl/%7Edraco/docs/voccomp.html) titled "Vocabula computatralia", apparently compiled by Konrad Kokoszkiewicz, provides some suggestions for computer-related jargon.

For "software" it directs to "program" and gives **programma, atis n.**

Not sure to what extent we can speak about "correct translation". A new word usually settled by the speaking/users community. Programma computatrale is used by [Vicipedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programma_computatrale) for computer program ("breviter programma"), can vouch for this selection.

Now, there appear to be some distinction between "software" and "computer program"; "software" being a more general term. A software, so it appears, contains computer program and other things. So as @jk - Reinstate Monica mentioned in a comment, it might be rendered as *Corpus programmatum*. But, it really depands what one means by software, which I believe many mean "computer program". At any case, I would vote to have *programma* for both "software" and "computer program"; for the later one might want to distinct by adding *computatrale*.

It should be noted that the Latin *programma* is a word that was used long before the emergence of those green boards.

Comment: See also: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/196/latin-word-for-code-or-program-the-verb

Comment: @cmw, thanks. maybe indeed there are better options then. though, in principle, I'm not against multiple meanings for the same word.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain in English there's a historical difference between program, application, and software.

Answer (score 1):

In Appendix V of *Conversational Latin for Oral Proficiency* by John C. Traupman, a software is **part·ēs -ium f. pl. programmātiōnis**.

This echoes d_e's response when they said:

> A software, so it appears, contains computer program and other thing.